# I cant see my citations or even bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex

Hi guys i am using a template for my bachelor thesis from a university in germany. I am using Texlive for the packages and Texmaker. In texmaker i configured the Bibtex compiler to biber %
I am also using Jabref.

Ill post the relevant code for the bibliography and citation:

```
\addbibresource{litaratur_BA.bib}

\begin{document}

\input{misc/setup.tex}

\newgeometry{   inner=2cm,      outer=2cm,      marginparwidth=0cm,     marginparsep=0mm,   bindingoffset=.5cm,     top=1.5cm,      bottom=2.5cm,   includehead,    includefoot      }


\addchap{Literaturverzeichnis}


\setlength\columnsep{2em}

\begin{multicols}{2}    \begin{refcontext}[sorting=nyt]         \renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\small\RaggedRight}        \linespread{1.0}\selectfont         \printbibliography[heading=none]    \end{refcontext} \end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

In my Setup.tex i have the following code related to my bibliography:

```
\usepackage[  backend=biber,  style=alphabetic,  doi=false,isbn=false,   terseinits=true,   giveninits=true,   sortcites=true,  language=english,  backref=true,  ]{biblatex}  \AtEveryBibitem{%  \clearlist{language}   \clearlist{extra}  }


\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%  backrefpage = {page},  backrefpages = {pages}, }
```

After i used the command `\cite{citation key}` or even `\citep{citation key}` (i am inserting the correct citation key) i first compile with lualatex and then twice with Bibtex and afterwards again with lualatex. In my pdf i cant see the citation and i cant see the bibliogrpahy. Only the citation and the bibliogrpahy doesnt work.
My main file in which everything is being loaded is called main. When i compile with bibtex i get the message "Error : could not start the command : biber "main"

Can someone pls help^^

Comment: Can you and did you run biber? // Usual order: a) edit your main.tex, b) compile it, c) run from a shell: biber main, d) compile main.tex a second time. // No biber run, no result. The second compile will replace placeholders as needed.

Comment: @MS-SPO if you mean by "run from a shell: biber main" change the compiler from lualatex to BibTex and compile it, then yes i did it in the order you said. It didnt work

Comment: Windows: CMD. Linux: bsh, csh, ksh etc. You need to execute biber, not run a latex compiler for step c)

Comment: @MS-SPO When i type in cmd (as an admin) biber main or even biber main.tex i get an error message which says that the commnad biber isnt recognized. Then i tried the command tlmgr install bibe and it also didnt work it says tlmgr isnt found. I opened the texlive and checked under "installed" if biber is installed and it is installed... ohh boi ohh boi i am lost xD

Comment: Now i can see the citation in my PDF but i have 2 issues. i used the command \cite[page 1]{Citation key}. First of all i cant see the [page 1] in the pdf and i cant see in the pdf my bibliography

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 has the details of how to configure your editor to run Biber. Of course if Biber is not installed on your system, you need to install it first. How that can be done depends on the TeX system you use and how it was installed. Generally speaking, if you use TeX live you can use `tlmgr` or one of its GUI frontends to install Biber. Note that even if Biber is installed, it may not be found, if the TeX Live binary directory is not added to the system path. Editors usually don't care about this, but if you run from the command line that is relevant.

Comment: Oh I just saw: You're the same person that posted https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/683015/35864. Can we infer from that that you did manage to install Biber?