# Biber cant find the needed .bcf file

Tags: biblatex, biber

Hello there i cant add my bibliography to my file. I am using Texlive and Texmaker. In texmaker i switched the setting from the configuration of bibtex to biber %. I also updated biber via shell command tlgmr update biber. When i type biber test into the shell command i get the following error:
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> biber test
INFO - This is Biber 2.19
INFO - Logfile is 'test.blg'
ERROR - Cannot find 'test.bcf'!
INFO - ERRORS: 1

My test.tex contains the following code:

> \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
>
> \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
> \usepackage[english]{babel}
> \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
>
> \usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}
>
> \addbibresource{literatur_BA.bib}
>
> \bibliography{literatur_BA}
>
> \begin{document}
>
> \cite{Epoxidharze}
>
> \printbibliogrpahy
>
> test
> \end{document}

The \printbibliography command doesnt do anything.
I can see the \cite in my pdf.

Comment: you should not call biber from `C:\WINDOWS\system32`. Switch to your document folder first.

Comment: Double check that your configuration is as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864. Biber should indeed be executed in the document folder and not in `C:\WINDOWS\system32`. If you say `biber <filename>` in `C:\WINDOWS\system32`, Biber will look for the file `C:\WINDOWS\system32\<filename>.bcf`, which is probably not there. It is a bit weird that Biber would be executed in that folder and pdfLaTeX in your standard document folder...

Comment: I fixed my problem. I updated the path of my environemnt and system variables and now it works.

Comment: Please post an answer below and accept it so that this post can also help other people

Answer (score 1):

I had to add the correct path of biber and texlive to my system environment and to the environment of my User.
D:\texlive\2022\bin\win32
D:\texlive\2023\bin\windows